# How set Window's property When A new WPF window Opened

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I want to set new window's property such as showIntaskbar==false in WPF in CefSharp.

I have implemented the interface of ILifeSpanHandler here is my code

```
public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
{
newBrowser = null;
Window newWindow = (Window)HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowInfo.WindowHandle).RootVisual;
newWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
return false;
}
```

but I get a error ,the windowinfo.WindowHandle's value awalys 0x0000000
please help me.

Comment: Firstly OnBeforePopup is called before the pop-up has been created, no window has been created at this point.  Secondly the default popup opened by CEF uses a native window,  you can customize the windows style through the http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_IWindowInfo_Style.htm property.